# Conditional count with dplyr and usual count in 1 code

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, count, conditional-statements

I was wondering the following: I got a data set with the following columns:

```
df <- data.frame(year = c(2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019), 
                 navfund = c(2000, 1000, 1200, 1100, 2000), 
                 Asset = c('s', 'f', 's', 'h', 's'))
```

```
year   navfund   Asset  
2018   2000      s       
2018   1000      f       
2018   1200       s      
2019   1100      h       
2019   2000      s       
...               
...
```

I would like to have it as follows: for each year i want to know the count of s and the fund for each year e.g.:

```
year    asset (#s)    fund
      2018     20          3150
I
```

```
df %>% group_by(Year,) %>% summarise(Fund = n_distinct(navfund, Asset_S = sum (Asset = "S")
```

this is the code I tried, but it doesnt work I hope anyone could help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create all variables inside a single `summarise`

```
df %>%
 group_by(year) %>%
 summarise(
    Fund = n_distinct(navfund),
    Asset_S = sum(Asset == "S")
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Vinicius Felix. However, when using the code you proposed, i get NA's for Asset_s, and when substituting "sum" for "n_distinct", it shows 3 for each grouped year.

Comment: Never mind, now it works, figured out that after sum(Asset == "S"), gotta add na.rm = T

Comment: Anyone an idea why the following code does not work? :    df %>%
 group_by(Year) %>%
 summarise(
    Fund = Sum(Asset)
    Asset_S = sum(Asset == "S")
    )

Comment: You are missing a comma between the two new variables created in summarise

Comment: Thank you Vinicius, i used the following code and it still gives me an error : df %>% group_by(Year) %>% summarise( Fund = Sum(Asset), Asset_S = sum(Asset == "S", na.rm = T) )

Comment: I updated my code, try now

Comment: Thank you again Vinicius, though, i want to replace Fund = n_distinct (navfund), by Fund = sum (Asset), turning into the following code: df %>% group_by(Year) %>% summarise( Fund = Sum(Asset), Asset_S = sum(Asset == "S") )

Comment: so, when using your code it works, but not when i use the code i mentioned above